# How to properly preserve relations between content items on export/import in Orchard?

Tags: orchardcms

I've read the [official documentation on creating 1:N and M:N relations](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardDoc/blob/master/Documentation/Creating-1-n-and-n-n-relations.markdown) and there's one particular aspect that isn't covered: support for importing and exporting the relations. Since the relation is defined implicitly using the primary keys (auto-incrementing integers), won't that be a problem when exporting the data for import in another environment (like in a backup/restore scenario)? For instance, the order of items should matter during the import. Also, the internal id values won't necessarily be the same after an import to a fresh Orchard installation (since they are auto-incrementing).

What is the preferred way of implementing relations that support importing and exporting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved by using the identity feature that is provided as part of the import/export api. Instead of referring to a primary key value that is pretty much guaranteed not to be valid on the target instance, it's generating a deterministic and unique id that enables proper transfer of items, including in cases of relationships. There are two identity providers out of the box. One uses the alias of the item (when that exists) and the other stores GUID (that's the identity part, used by widgets for example).

Comment: That sounds good, but how does that fit with the table column conventions etc outlined in the documentation? Is it still possible to just add a property of type `SomeRelatedRecord` to `SomeRecord` together with a column in the corresponding database table and have Orchard/NHibernate treat this as a relation?

Comment: That sounds like a completely different question.

Comment: Then I have failed to properly describe the issue I'm facing. I followed the guidelines in https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardDoc/blob/master/Documentation/Creating-1-n-and-n-n-relations.markdown to create a relationship but also wanted to have it persisted between import/export. Will that require a completely different solution?

Comment: So now we're back to discussing import/export. nHibernate plays no role in import/export. Import/export behavior is determined by the import and export methods of each part driver. So it does not matter what the table column conventions are or how the relationship is implemented over the database. It's the drivers alone that will determine the import/export behavior. When you write the part that implements the relationship, just take advantage of the identity feature to persist and retrieve related items into and from xml. You should look at existing examples of relations.